# Best startegy for User navigation on details form

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot

Want to design a form where user fills incremental forms, like first personal info , then click Next and fill employment info click next and so on.

Using AngularJS, do i need to call DB save with every Next button OR Just hiding old section and showing next section will work. If i go with ng-hide\show, values in the old input fields are lost obviously.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state management like `ngrx` or any `Subject` provided by `rxjs` to keep your state alive. Your data won't be lost. Eg : Use `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` to pass/store the data. Be careful `ngrx` is a good state management, but not mandatory. If you don't know ngrx, use `Subject`. Because Subject is pretty much easier than ngrx and ngrx makes your project mess if you don't handle it in a proper way.